# MySQL - How to get number of comments from the comment table in one query, JOIN with 3 other tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, optimization, mariadb

I am new at MySQL, but I was testing out and creating a somewhat of a group function that you see in eg.: 'Facebook'. And I wanted to display a listing of all the Group Posts that the logged in User joined, and how many comments it has.

Tables:
group_table -> contains all the groups
user_table -> contains all the users
group_users -> now, this contains each users that are linked to each group
                     eg: groupuser: 1 | groupid: 4 | admin: 1 (bool)
post_table -> contains all the posts
comment_table -> contains all the comments

So... this was my attempt at it:

```
SELECT pt.postid, pt.postcont, pt.ctime, gt.groupname, 
COUNT(cm.commid) AS commNumber 
FROM post_table pt 
INNER JOIN group_users gu 
ON pt.gid = gu.gid 
INNER JOIN group_table gt
ON gu.gid = gt.gid
LEFT JOIN comment_table cm 
ON pt.postid = cm.postid
WHERE gu.groupuserid = {user_id}
```

What I want the results to show:

postid | postcontent | ctime | groupname | commentNumber

1           loremipsum   {date}  coolgroup      if there is any comment then display {nr of comments otherwise 0}

but at the moment, the problem is that only the posts that contain a comment are being retrieved and showing in the results (commNumber is correct), but those who don't have a comment instead of showing '0' for commNumber, the post itself isn't being retrieved

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: you can try this 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner2

Comment: @A.ANoman: good edit, but we tend to think that "Thanks for your help" etc does not need to be added - we take these out anyway.

Comment: @A.ANoman I have tried inner joins, but t doesn't seem to work

Comment: Where is the Group by Clause?

Comment: @AnkitBajpaiu i didn't understand your question